# DOJO DataGrid - how to get the index (number) of first visible row and the last visible row

Tags: javascript, datagrid, dojo

How can I read index of the first and the last visible rows in dojox.grid.DataGrid ?

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grid's scroller has properties:

```
dojox.grid.scroller.firstVisibleRow
```

and

```
dojox.grid.scroller.lastVisibleRow
```

Worked nicely for me some time ago :-)

See also: http://dojotoolkit.org/api/1.3/dojox/grid/scroller